# How dBuV value changes with distance?

Tags: radio, decibel, emissions

I've got an emissions source that's designed to generate a peak at a certain frequency that when measured by an antenna 3m away gives a value of X dBuV.

If the emissions source if moved closer to the antenna at 1m away, what should I expect the dBuV reading to be? (ignoring any other effects such as reflections)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electric field amplitude of an electromagnetic wave falls as 1/d in the far field. If you look at the power density it falls as \$1/d^2\$

Going to dB scale you must do 10log p (p is power density) so it depends on 20log d (because d was squared). The dB increase is therefore 20log(3/1)=9.5 dB.

Note that the previous calculation is only valid if we're working at the far field (boundary between near and far field depends on \$\lambda\$, i.e. on the transmitter frequency). In the near field you'll have inductive or capacitive coupling between transmitter and receiver, and not simply radiative coupling, so that the power increase by approaching the antennas would be much bigger.

Answer (score 0):

E = kQ/r²

In first case you have 3m and in second case you have 2m let's suppose you will got

Z = A/9 for the first and Y = A/4 for the second. So, rearranging Y/Z = 9/4 = 2.25

So I would expect a 2.25Z as result. Of course, simplifying at maximum your problem.

Since you are talking on logarithmic scale we have 20log(2.25) = 16.2186 dB
Finally you will got about 16.2186 + X db

Comment: 2 meters (3 minus 1)

Comment: Oh, I guess you were saying for 1 meter of distance instead of 2, right?

Applying the same equations will give you more 43.9445 dB in relation to X

Comment: @PedroQuadros, dB uses decimal logarithm and not neperian logarithm.

Comment: I know it, maybe it was a mistake by wolframalpha